# Is it correct to say "I feel painful" to mean "I feel pain"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, phrases, adjectives, sense-verbs

Is it correct to say "I feel painful" to mean "I feel pain"?

Please note that I mean only those cases, in which the phrase is a complete sentence. There should be no words after the last word in each quote (like in "I feel painful pulses in my head", "I feel painful burning sensations in my stomach", etc.)

If it's correct, what is the slight difference in meaning there?

Comment: ~brilliant, I changed *meaning* to *to mean*. Also, it really is incorrect to have a period in those quotes, but I retained them due to the way you phrased your question. Without the periods, both would still be taken as full sentences. They would only be considered as parts of a bigger sentence if followed by ellipses: "I feel painful...", "I feel pain..."

Comment: @Jimi Oke: "it really is incorrect to have a period in those quotes" - Why is it incorrect?

Comment: Because the final period within a pair of quotes terminates the entire sentence. If not, the quoted text should terminate with a comma. Thus, your title should be: (with comma overload) *Is it correct to say, "I feel painful," to mean, "I feel pain"?* or (without comma overload) *Is it correct to say "I feel painful" to mean "I feel pain"?* And you could always explain the specific usage within the body of question, e.g. *no words after the last word in each quote*, and so on.

Comment: @Jimi Oke: WOW!!! That's amazing! Thank you. I've already edited my question. Do you have any link to some official resource on the web that states these rules of proper quoting?

Comment: @Jimi Oke: Jimi, please, take a look at the very first sentence in the answer provided here by AAT: *No, it is not correct English to say "I feel painful."* Is his quoting also wrong?

Comment: There are actually two schools, one that wants punctuation within quotes even though it isn't really part of the quote, and another that puts them outside. I believe the former school should mend its evil ways; but it still has some adherents.

Comment: @brilliant: You're welcome. Here are a couple links: [Purdue OWL](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/577/03/), [Quotation Marks](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/quotation.htm#footnote). In American English, the comma and period always goes within the quotation marks, regardless of logic. In British English, however, this is not the case. More on that [here](http://grammartips.homestead.com/inside.html). Also, for consistency's sake, as per my previous comment, I think you should just remove the comma after "I feel painful,"

Comment: @brilliant: As for AAT's *No, it is not correct English to say "I feel painful."*, strictly speaking, there ought to be a comma after *say*. Otherwise, the punctuation is perfectly correct, as the period terminates the entire sentence. A British/International English writer, however, may be inclined to place the period *after* the quotation mark, not *before*, as in: *No, it is not correct English to say "I feel painful".* But I doubt such a writer would if they placed a comma after *say*: *No, it is not correct English to say, "I feel painful."*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not correct English to say "I feel painful."

You can say "I feel pain", or "I am in pain", because 'pain' is a noun, but "painful" is an adjective so you would need to use it qualify something else (as in your "I feel painful sensations" example).

Comment: @AAT: Thank you for your answer. You have confirmed my suspicions. "*... but "painful" is an adjective so you would need to use...*" - Is having an adjective really a valid basis for deeming "I am <adjective>." phrases as wrong? Look: "I feel happy", "I feel sick", "I feel hungry" - as far as I know, all these phrases are correct, but they all contain adjectives.

Comment: @brilliant: The reason *painful* is wrong is not because it is an adjective, but because of the meaning of *painful*.  Something that is painful is the cause of pain: a painful injury, a painful memory, a painful needle, but not a "painful person" or "painful dog" (to mean that they *have* pain).

Comment: Something that is painful can also be what is affected by pain, e.g. "a painful arm".

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Could we just say that any adjective that is derived from a noun by means of adding "-ful" is not good for "*I feel* <adjective>." complete sentence? I remember, once I said "*I feel shameful*" and a native speaker corrected me right away: "*I feel ashamed*". Or, perhaps, we could put it this way: "*I feel* <adjective>." would be correct only if replacing "*feel*" with "*am*" will not change the meaning.

Comment: @brilliant: It's just not true though.  "I feel hopeful" = fine.  "I feel joyful" = fine.  *Thankful*, *playful*, *merciful*, *forgetful*... also fine.

Comment: @mizo: There is another word for something affected by pain - it's called "sore". If you search "sore arm" on google you get twice as more results compared to "painful arm", and many "painful arm" results actually have the form "painful arm X" where X is something that causes the pain.

Comment: @Artem: I don't really care for Google statistics. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/painful makes this claim: "2. Afflicted or suffering with pain (of a body part or, formerly, of a person). [from 15th c.]"

Comment: @Kosmonaut: (1) Yes, you are right. *Hopeful, joyful, merciful* unlike *painful* are all fine. So, what kind of rule can we come up with here? The thing is I don't really think that "whether-it-is-a-cause-or-not" method would work here. Although, as you have rightly said here, "*painful*" could mean "*causing the feeling of pain*", other "*-ful*" adjectives may not convey that connotation. For example, a person can be joyful merely by himself without making others to be joyful. Same with *thankful* and *merciful*. Plus, as Mizo has noted, we can also say "*a painful arm*" and

Comment: @Kosmonaut: (2) here, of course, the arm is not the cause of pain. I think the key is in whether or not that adjective can be applied to a person. While *hopeful, thankful, joyful, merciful* can all qualify a person, *painful* can only be applied to some situations (for example, dilemma), events or processes (for example, history, outcome, procedure) and parts of body (for example, arm, leg, finger), but not to a person. So, here is my

Comment: @Kosmonaut: (3) proposition: "ADJECTIVES ENDING ON "-FUL" AND DENOTING SOME KIND OF FEELING CAN BE USED IN "I FEEL <ADJECTIVE>" COMPLETE SENTENCES ONLY IF THEY CAN QUALIFY A PERSON". What do you think?

Comment: @brilliant: What is the purpose of making a "rule" like that?  There is no syntactic restriction that makes "I feel painful" wrong.  It is just wrong because of the meaning of *painful*; it sounds like you are saying that you feel like you cause pain.  If there is any rule at play here, it is: "use the word that means the thing you want it to mean".

Comment: @Kosmonaut: (1) Perhaps, I should not have used the word *rule* here. I just want to get to the bottom of this question: Why some "-ful" adjectives go along well with "I feel ..." while others don't. I agree that there are no syntactic restrictions here, but my concern is more on the side of meaning, rather than grammar. Perhaps, for native speakers this kind of research would seem quite pointless, but it may prove very helpful for those whose first language is not English. I have met many learners of

Comment: @Kosmonaut: (2) English who were really surprised when they were told that "I feel painful" doesn't mean "I feel pain". In fact, I am on of them.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: (3) "*If there is any rule at play here, it is: "use the word that means the thing you want it to mean*" - If I try to follow this logic I may get into the same trap again: I know that to say "My painful arm" is correct and that that would mean "My arm feels pain", thus, I would think, since it's okay to say "I feel pain" (meaning that it is me who is feeling pain), then it must also be okay to say "I feel painful", and the meaning (as I would think) would still be the same as in case with "painful arm".

Comment: Dear all, I think it makes sense to take such extended follow-up discussions to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage), as the main site is not really designed to accommodate them.

Comment: @Kosmonaut There is a _possible_ usage of "I feel painful", at least in British English, but it's unlikely to be used. There's an idiomatic use of 'painful' to describe someone whose public performance is embarassing or really tedious as in "He sings karaoke but he's so tone deaf he's painful" (i e he causes emotional pain to others). It is _just_ possible that somone could be placed in a situation where they had to make a speech, say, but knew that their performance was terrible. It would then be possible that they could say "I felt painful all the time". As I said, not likely but possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel pain you *hurt*.  When, say, getting over a case of the flu one might say "I hurt all over."  If you sprain your ankle you'd say "my ankle hurts".

Answer (score 0):

I apologize in advance for

AAT is right; Grammatically, the phrase "I feel painful" is incorrect.  You cannot use an adjective as a modifier for **feel**.  However, it is perfectly acceptable to, instead of using the qualifier AAT suggested (*"I feel painful **sensations**"*), you may also opt to use an object:  *I feel **pain***.

So your options are as follows (using *I feel* **__** as the template):

- use a noun to qualify the adjective **painful** (*I feel
  painful **bites***)
- use a noun as a direct object to enhance the verb **feel** (*I feel **pain***)
- use an adverb to enhance the verb **feel** (*I feel painfully **sick***)

Editorial note: When a sentence gets cloudy like this (it's bound to happen, ESPECIALLY in English), your best bet is to try to find a suitable synonym, preferably one that is interchangeable and not cluttered with subtle connotations. (instead of **uncomfortable** to express pain, perhaps **excruciating** will do instead)  Worst case scenario, you're better off rebuilding the whole sentence.  It happens.

Hope this helps

Comment: @ Rant: No, you and ATT are incorrect. There is nothing grammatically wrong with putting an adjective after _feel_ when, as here, it's used as a linking verb.  
The adjective would modify the subject, not the verb. (You cannot use an adjective _or_ an adverb to modify a linking verb.) And the adjective can even end in _-ful_, as in "I feel wonderful." The problem with _painful_ is purely semantic.

Answer (score -2):

Only Hot Lick's is correct.

We can say:
I feel happy.
I feel excited.

However,  we cannot say:
I feel happiness.
I feel excitement.

The experience was painful.
It means,  the experience caused pain to you.

Comment: I can absolutely  say "I feel happiness" or "I feel excitement".

Comment: Of course you can say "I feel happiness", you hear it said all the time.